# Html Parsing vs. Regex

Tags: python, html, regex, scala, html-parsing

I have a fixed well structured html source, incoming data is clear and small, just contains a little list of divs. I know that using a html parser for html parsing but this looks like a particular case and i am not sure which one that i should use. The problem conditions below

- Data is clear and well structured
- Data is small
- Performance matters, application must be able to get as much as data that is possibble
- Application will write data to MongoDB database
- Implementation programming language will be Scala or Python

Any opinion is valuable so what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would still stick to using an HTML Parser, because, at least, there is a specific data format and a specialized tool that understands the format.

If performance matters here, there is a blazingly fast [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) package. For the HTML, use [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html).

You can also use an awesome [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package and [let it use `lxml` parser under-the-hood](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use). Besides, if the data you need to parse is in a specific part of the HTML document, you can have a performance gain by asking `BeautifulSoup` to parse only the relevant part of the HTML document, see more at: [Parsing only part of a document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document).

And, to follow the tradition for HTML+regex threads, here is the reference to the famous topic covering the reasons why you should not use regex for parsing HTML:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I know that what i shouldn't use regex to html parsing, i know what is regex and what it turns when implemented,yes i got automata lesson too, most of reasons are about html unstable structres and big amount of data, which is not true for our case, we have a well structred and small data to process. so, i appreciate your answer but this is not we are lookng for, i think.

Comment: @HüseyinZengin thanks. It's difficult to say without seeing what kind of data you have, how much of it and what data you need to parse from it. I guess your best bet would be to measure the performance yourself. For example, implement it using `lxml` and `regex`-only approach and benchmark it.